# how disable button accept and reject after changing status?

Tags: javascript, php

how  **disable buttons accept and reject after changing the status** to approved or rejected of each row
(when the user do a rental  in website .In admin panel the admin have to accept or refuse the rental then the status has change to approved if he choose accept and rejected if he choose refuse and then the buttons should be disable).

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["approved"]))
{ 
    $id_location=$_POST['id_location'];
$sql="UPDATE location SET etat = 'Approved' WHERE id_location = '$id_location'";
mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

}
if(isset($_POST["rejected"]))
{ 
    $id_location=$_POST['id_location'];
$sql="UPDATE location SET etat='Rejected' WHERE id_location = '$id_location'";
mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
}
?>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
            Rentals</h6>
           
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

<div class="container">
    
<div class="row justify-content-center">


    <?php 

/*$query="SELECT  * from voiture v,location l,user u where v.id_voiture=l.id_voiture AND l.id_user=u.id_user";
*/
$query="select * from (voiture v right join location l on (v.id_voiture=l.id_voiture)) inner join user u on (l.id_user=u.id_user)";
$query_run=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0){



?>
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>User</th>
                <th>Car</th>
                <th>Modele</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>mileage</th>
                <th>prix</th>
                <th>from date</th>
                <th>to date</th>
                <th>person</th>
                <th>luggage</th>
                 <th>status</th>
                <th >accept</th>
                <th >Delete</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    

<?php
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
    

?>

<tr>

    <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nom'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['model'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['type'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['kilometrage'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['prix'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['from_date'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['to_date'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['person'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['luggage'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['etat'];?></td>
 
    <td><form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_location" value="<?php echo $row['id_location']; ?>">
        <button  type="submit" name="approved"  class="btn btn-success"  >approved</button></form></td>
    <td><form method="post"  action="">
<input type="hidden" name="id_location" value="<?php echo $row['id_location']; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="rejected" class="btn btn-danger"  >reject</button></form></td>
    



    
</td> 
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>    
<?php } ?>

</div>



    
</form>
`
```

Comment: You _have_ the `etat` value available, you _know_ how `if` and `else` work … what more do you need?

Comment: script javascript

Comment: Why would this need any JavaScript? You are submitting your form by clicking any of these buttons, which means the server will respond with a _new_ result page anyway - so anything you would have done on the current page via JS, would be “lost” after you submitted the form.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Handle it there, where you create this table. You _have_ the `etat` value available at that point - so use it, to decide whether to output the HTML code for a disabled button, or a not disabled one …

Comment: can you clarify more

Comment: What exactly needs more clarification? You know what the HTML code for a disabled button should look like, yes or no? You know how if/else work. So …?

Comment: why don't you try ajax for this ?? have look at https://www.studentstutorial.com/ajax/update-data.php

Comment: it's hard .I am beginner

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. just added two if condition in button section.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST["approved"])){ 
       $id_location=$_POST['id_location'];
       $sql="UPDATE location SET etat = 'Approved' WHERE id_location = '$id_location'";
       mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
   }

   if(isset($_POST["rejected"])){ 
       $id_location=$_POST['id_location'];
        $sql="UPDATE location SET etat='Rejected' WHERE id_location = '$id_location'";
        mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
   }
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
           <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
              Rentals
           </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                   <?php 
                      /*$query="SELECT  * from voiture v,location l,user u where v.id_voiture=l.id_voiture AND l.id_user=u.id_user";
                      */
                      $query="select * from (voiture v right join location l on (v.id_voiture=l.id_voiture)) inner join user u on (l.id_user=u.id_user)";
                      $query_run=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                      if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0){ ?>
                           <table class="table">
                              <thead>
                                 <tr>
                                    <th>User</th>
                                    <th>Car</th>
                                    <th>Modele</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>mileage</th>
                                    <th>prix</th>
                                    <th>from date</th>
                                    <th>to date</th>
                                    <th>person</th>
                                    <th>luggage</th>
                                    <th>status</th>
                                    <th >accept</th>
                                    <th >Delete</th>
                                 </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                 <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) { ?>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['nom'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['model'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['type'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['kilometrage'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['prix'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['from_date'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['to_date'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['person'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['luggage'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['etat'];?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php if($row['etat'] == "Rejected" || $row['etat']==""){ ?>
                                           <form method="post" action="">
                                              <input type="hidden" name="id_location" value="<?php echo $row['id_location']; ?>">
                                              <button  type="submit" name="approved"  class="btn btn-success"  >approved</button>
                                           </form>
                                        <?php }?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php if($row['etat'] == "Approved" || $row['etat']==""){ ?>
                                           <form method="post"  action="">
                                              <input type="hidden" name="id_location" value="<?php echo $row['id_location']; ?>">
                                              <button type="submit" name="rejected" class="btn btn-danger"  >reject</button>
                                           </form>
                                        <?php }?>
                                    </td>
                                    </td> 
                                 </tr>
                                 <?php } ?>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                   <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```